# tensorflow dataset direct normalization

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, normalization

```
def get_dataset(file_path, **kwargs):
    dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
      file_path,
      batch_size=5, # Artificially small to make examples easier to show.
      label_name=LABEL_COLUMN,
      na_value="?",
      num_epochs=1,
      ignore_errors=True, 
      **kwargs)
    return dataset

CSV_COLUMNS = ['survived', 'sex', 'age', 'n_siblings_spouses', 'parch', 'fare', 'class', 'deck', 'embark_town', 'alone']

TRAIN_DATA_URL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv"    
train_file_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file("train.csv", TRAIN_DATA_URL)
temp_dataset = get_dataset(train_file_path, column_names=CSV_COLUMNS)
```

Is it possible to directly normalize the temp_dataset *without exporting the data to other data library for further manipulation*?? (some columns are numeric and others are categorical)

Answer (score 0):

I would to first read the CSV file with Pandas. Use the `map` function to normalize the column,

```
# Read the CSV
df = pd.read_csv( 'train.csv' )

# Normalize the "temp" column
df[ 'temp' ] = df[ 'temp' ].map( lambda x : x / SOME_NUMBER )
```

Now, save the modified CSV,

```
df.to_csv( 'data.csv' , sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

Now, pass this CSV file to `make_csv_dataset()` like,

```
dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
      'data.csv',
      batch_size=5, # Artificially small to make examples easier to show.
      label_name=LABEL_COLUMN,
      na_value="?",
      num_epochs=1,
      ignore_errors=True, 
      **kwargs)
```

This could be a short trick to normalize a single column and then forge it into a `tf.data.Dataset`. For more details, refer to this [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#consuming_csv_data).

Comment: Thanks.for the quick reply. It would appear to me also this is the only solution. The tensorflow dataset is not design for data manipulation. It is a final data wrapper before it is being feed into the model.